# iterate on python list (a list from second item from another list)

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy

I have a list of the form:

```py
[['id_5', 4], ['id_6', 4], ['id_7', 4], ['id_0', 12], ['id_1', 4], ['id_2', 8], ['id_3', 8], ['id_4', 4], ['id_8', 1]]
[['id_5', 5], ['id_6', 5], ['id_7', 5], ['id_0', 15], ['id_1', 5], ['id_2', 10], ['id_3', 10], ['id_4', 5]]
```

I want just the second element of every list.

Desired output:

```py
[4,4,4,12,4,8,8,4,1]
[5,5,5,15,5,10,10,5]
```

Or:

```py
4 4 4 12 4 8 8 4 1 
5 5 5 15 5 10 10 5
```

I tried this code:

```py
for i in range(0,len(vectorized)):
    for j in range (0,len(vectorized[i])):
        print(vectorized[i][j][1])
```

But my output is:

```
4
4
4
12
4
...
```

Thank you.

Comment: Use `list(zip(*mylist))[1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try list comprehension :

```
list1 = [['id_5', 4], ['id_6', 4], ['id_7', 4], ['id_0', 12], ['id_1', 4], ['id_2', 8], ['id_3', 8], ['id_4', 4], ['id_8', 1]]
list2 = [['id_5', 5], ['id_6', 5], ['id_7', 5], ['id_0', 15], ['id_1', 5], ['id_2', 10], ['id_3', 10], ['id_4', 5]]
list1_out = [i[1] for i in list1]
list2_out = [i[1] for i in list2]
```

**Output** :

```
[4, 4, 4, 12, 4, 8, 8, 4, 1] # list1_out
[5, 5, 5, 15, 5, 10, 10, 5] # list2_out
```

Comment: ```
for i in range(0,len(list1)):   
  print ( [i[1] for i in list1[i]])
```

Answer (score 2):

There are different approaches, a simple comprehension would do:

```
[x[1] for x in l]
```

Also with `map` and [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter
list(map(itemgetter(1), l))
```

For printing the results you can call print with unpacking:

```
print(*out_list)
```

For example:

```
>>> l = [['id_5', 4], ['id_6', 4], ['id_7', 4], ['id_0', 12], ['id_1', 4], ['id_2', 8], ['id_3', 8], ['id_4', 4], ['id_8
', 1]]
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> out_list = list(map(itemgetter(1), l))
>>> out_list
[4, 4, 4, 12, 4, 8, 8, 4, 1]
>>> print(*out_list)
4 4 4 12 4 8 8 4 1
```

All as a one liner:

```
>>> print(*(x[1] for x in l))
4 4 4 12 4 8 8 4 1
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
a = [['id_5', 4], ['id_6', 4], ['id_7', 4], ['id_0', 12], ['id_1', 4], ['id_2', 8], ['id_3', 8], ['id_4', 4], ['id_8', 1]]
b = [['id_5', 5], ['id_6', 5], ['id_7', 5], ['id_0', 15], ['id_1', 5], ['id_2', 10], ['id_3', 10], ['id_4', 5]]
x = list(list(zip(*a))[1])
y = list(list(zip(*b))[1])
print(x)
print(y)
```

**Output:-**

```
[4, 4, 4, 12, 4, 8, 8, 4, 1]
[5, 5, 5, 15, 5, 10, 10, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something you're overcomplicating. Just iterate through the main list and print the 2nd element of the list you get on each loop, e.g.:

```
for i in big_list:
    print i[1]
```

Python is has some really nice ways of iterating through lists so you don't need to use the range method.

Comment: the sub lists of the big list are not the same size

Comment: why does their size matter? You said you want the 2nd item - i[1] gets the 2nd item

Comment: thought I did just realise that you wanted the output as another list so using Arkistarvh Kltzuonstev's answer above is more what you want